# Пара вопросов по верстке. Как исправить?

Tags: css

Верстаю [сайт](http://evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/). Первый вопрос: при наведении мышки на пункт Главного меню почему оно не подсвечивается на всю ширину (от правого до левого border'a)? Какое CSS правило нужно прописать?

Второй вопрос: если прокрутить страницу вниз до пункта "TESTIMONIALS", там заголовок сделан как h5 с классом "h5". Я прописал такие CSS стили:

```
h5.h5:before{
    background-image: url(http://evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/30/2015/02/h5.png);
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 101px;
    height: 79px;
}
```

Но картинка не отображается, почему так происходит?

Comment: если используете before - необходимо прописать content: '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список меню li через **display-inline**.

Большинство браузеров разделяет строчные блоки отступами.

Для того чтобы этого небыло, варианты, как от этого избавиться:

1) родителю **font-size: 0px;** это свойство наследуется, и перебить его для самих потомков

shortcodes.css:4038

```
#top .av-submenu-pos-center { 
  font-size: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

2) список в одну строку

```
<ul>
<li>Стороки.</li><li>Просто</li><li>строки</li>
</ul>
```

3) не закрывать тег li

```
 <ul>
        <li>Стороки.
        <li>Просто
        <li>строки
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы отображалась картинка с кавычками, нужно сделать padding, а не margin. И никакого псевдокласса before не нужно

```
h5.h5 {
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 70px;
background-image: url("//evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/30/2015/02/h5.png");
background-size: 50px 40px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```